# How to get a result in a form without complex numbers?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, complex

How can I get rid of the complex numbers in this result?  The actual result is obviously real, but Mathematica gives me this inconvenient complex form.

```
Integrate[Exp[a*(x^3)], {x, 0, b}, Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0}]

((1 - I Sqrt[3]) (Gamma[1/3] - Gamma[1/3, -a b^3]))/(6 a^(1/3))
```

And I've already seen this related question, but the methods suggested for that problem didn't work for this.  ComplexExpand[] just makes it into an absolute mess, and Simply puts it right back into complex form.

[How to get rid of all complex numbers and functions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42438/how-to-get-rid-of-all-complex-numbers-and-functions)

Answer (score 1):

Here is dirty trick suitable for that particular case:

```
rez = Integrate[Exp[5*(x^3)], {x, 0, 7}, 
   Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0}] // ToRadicals

rezComplex = 
 Integrate[Exp[a*(x^3)], {x, 0, b}, Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0}]

realAnswer = (rez // ToRadicals) /. {5 -> a, -1715 -> -a*b^3}

FullSimplify[(realAnswer - rezComplex), Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0}]
(* 0*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following trick:

```
realPartRule = Complex[re_, im_] :> Complex[re, 0];
realPart[exp__] := exp /. realPartRule;
```

Applying this trick to your result we obtain:

```
realPart[Integrate[Exp[a*(x^3)], {x, 0, b}, 
Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0}]]
(*(Gamma[1/3] - Gamma[1/3, -a b^3])/(6 a^(1/3))*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume a<0 instead of a>0 and use -a

```
Integrate[Exp[-a*(x^3)], {x, 0, b}, Assumptions -> {a < 0, b > 0}]

(*   (Gamma[1/3] - Gamma[1/3, a b^3])/(3 a^(1/3))   *)
```

Or use Sqrt[a^2] with a>0

```
Integrate[Exp[Sqrt[a^2]*(x^3)], {x, 0, b}, Assumptions -> {b > 0}] // 
   Simplify[#, a > 0] &

(*   (Gamma[1/3] - Gamma[1/3, -a b^3])/(3 (-a)^(1/3))   *)
```

But now intermediate imaginary terms (like a^1/3 of a negative number) are only hidden.